Error deploying angular app with scripts to Vercel
I am getting the below error
[ERROR] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/src/js/external-script.js' [plugin angular-script-global]

angular.json
  "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "./src/js/external-script.js"
]
             

local build works.

First move the "external-script.js" to the assets or public folder.
Then make sure you have that folder added to the assets array of angular.json.
  "assets": ["/src/assets"],

This will ensure your script is discoverable when angular builds the application.
Reference Answer
Then Reference that file from the scripts array of angular.json.
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
    "./src/assets/external-script.js"
]
 

